# Problems trying to build custom micropython firmware for STM32

Tags: c, micropython

I am trying to build custom Micropython firmware with ethernet support for STM32F407VE. I've forked working board without ethernet support and trying to modify it with ethernet support.

**Things I have done:**

- defined `MICROPY_HW_ETH_*` variables in `mpconfigboard.h`
- added `MICROPY_PY_LWIP = 1` to `mpconfigboard.mk`
- added `ETH_*` pins to `pins.csv`
- added additional pins from Port F, G, H, I to `pins.csv`

Here is my modified board: https://github.com/untitledlt/BLACK_F407VE

**Now when I'm trying to build it, i get:**

```
In file included from eth.c:31:
eth.c: In function 'eth_mac_init':
eth.c:163:106: error: implicit declaration of function 'STATIC_AF_ETH_RMII_REF_CLK'; did you mean 'STATIC_AF_ETH_RMII__REF_CLK'? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     mp_hal_pin_config_alt_static(MICROPY_HW_ETH_RMII_REF_CLK, MP_HAL_PIN_MODE_ALT, MP_HAL_PIN_PULL_NONE, STATIC_AF_ETH_RMII_REF_CLK);
                                                                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pin_static_af.h:42:48: note: in definition of macro 'mp_hal_pin_config_alt_static'
         mp_hal_pin_config(pin_obj, mode, pull, fn_type(pin_obj)) /* Overflow Error => alt func not found */
                                                ^~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [build-BLACK_F407VE/eth.o] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried asking on [the MicroPython forum](https://forum.micropython.org)?

Comment: Yes, I did: https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=7202

Comment: You posted that in the ESP32 subforum, but you're not asking about an ESP32 - I would try reposting in [Other Boards](https://forum.micropython.org/viewforum.php?f=12)

Comment: My bad. Reposted under Other boards.

Comment: Did you try reading the error message and taking its suggestions?  specifically the correct number of underscores in `STATIC_AF_ETH_RMII__REF_CLK`

Comment: Sure but that's just a guess from compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug (typo) in Micropython branch.
`ETH_RMII__REF_CLK` should be replaced with `ETH_RMII_REF_CLK` in `ports/stm32/boards/stm32f405_af.csv` file.

It's already fixed by https://github.com/micropython/micropython/pull/5308.

All Credit goes to Mike Causer.

Thanks, Mike!

Comment: No worries! I’m still waiting for my board to arrive from China so I can test it myself